# Eclipse Kepler: #include "boost/filesystem.hpp" breaking debugging?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, boost

I have a fresh install of Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 x64. My first "Hello world" worked great, including setting breakpoints and walking through code in debug mode. My second program links to Boost. I can set the breakpoints, build 'Debug' without errors, and run Debug, but unlike my Hello World, it blows through my breakpoints. The console window appears to flicker "Info: Nothing to build for..." and then clears. None of my std::cout calls appear.

With a little debugging I found that commenting out "filesystem.hpp" (below) enables the debugging, but of course I need it. I'm new to Eclipse. What would cause this behavior?

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp" <--- removing this enables debugging
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Start search" << std::endl;
               :
               :
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the build output/problems views.

Most likely, you don't link to the required lib(s) for Boost Filesystem (`-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`).

In effect this just means that no executable is built, and obviously therefore cannot be started.

Comment: Thanks. Everything builds properly Turns out it wasn't linking to the Boost DLLs at runtime. I can drop the DLLs into the executable's folder and everything then runs fine. What's the preferred way to specify the path to Boost's DLLs through the Eclipse IDE?